# how to assign the Variable values of one to a list to another list

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

```
Class AR
{

public int inv {get;}

public ClassD[] dE {get; set;}

}

Class ClassD : ST

{

 public ClassA AD {get; set;}

 // other variables are also defined

}

Class Ag : CT

{

public int inv {get; set;}

public ClassA AD {get; set;}

 // other variables are also defined

}
```

Above  three classes are pre-defined , Now the code  need to below stuff :

`var SE = Prof(int id); // This will return the AR Class object in a list`,

Now i need to create a new list for Ag Class object and assign the values for it from the list SE. (problem is how i should assign the AD value in AG Class.

```
// Some thing like this?

var TE = SE.Add(inv)
```

Comment: Please elaborate more and provide code to understand more.

Comment: Please show the class structure. Description is very vague

Comment: @ManishM  Updated the question.

Comment: What is `Prof`? Where is this called in relation to your classes? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Adriani6 it is method which will return the AR class object, input for the method is id, i able to get the output from this method, the one problem i need to assign the data to other list ot from this output data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood your question, you need to map `List<AR>` to `List<AG>`. You can do it with Linq in such manner:

```
List<AR> SE = Prof(id);
List<AG> TE = SE.Select(s =>
    new AG
    {
        // set inv property
        inv = s.inv,

        // dE is an array of ClassD instances, 
        //so to get some single ClassA instance for setting AD property you can do:
        // AD = s.dE.Single().AD
        //or
        // AD = s.dE.FirstOrDefault()?.AD
    }).ToList();
```

Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes.. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Happy to help, @Urao.